# Get Header and Request Body from Microsoft Network Monitor 3.4

Tags: networking, tcp, wireshark, fiddler, packet-capture

I need to read the requests and responses from a particular desktop app, I have been able to capture requests and responses from Microsoft Network Monitor. How can I get the Headers and Response Body like Postman. I need to stimulate similar behaviour in my app.